# Did Germany build their own training camp in Brazil in preparation for the World Cup?

Tags: sport, football, brazil

[This article](http://www.independent.ie/sport/soccer/world-cup/special-soap-bananas-and-silent-airconditioning-brazilian-hoteliers-surprised-by-world-cup-teams-extravagant-demands-30263544.html) claims:

> The Germans have made by far the most extravagant preparations. The
>   delegation has built its own training facility in the scenic village
>   of Santo André in Bahia, and the headquarters for coach Joachim Low's
>   team is a gated community with 13 houses, 65 rooms, a football field
>   and press centre.

This seems like an overshot to build your own base just for the World Cup. Is it in fact true or they merely rented the place? Or maybe they build a lot of facilities worldwide regularly and this is just one of those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may sound like overkill, but the fact is true that the German Football Association (Deutscher Fußball Bund) built this facility with the help of some private investors who will use this as a vacation camp later.

For more information look at wikipedia [Campo Bahia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campo_Bahia)

> Campo Bahia is the purpose-built training camp of the Germany national football team team for the 2014 FIFA World Cup.[1] It is situated in the village of Santo André, on the Southern tip of the state of Bahia in the North-East region of Brazil. It is about eight kilometers north of Santa Cruz Cabrália, and 30 kilometers north of Porto Seguro, on the Atlantic coast of Brazil.
>
> The facility will reportedly cost around £25 million, and will be funded by the German Football Association as well as private industry. The Germany team is the first occupant of the facilities. After the World Cup the resort will be opened to the public. The resort covers 15,000 square meters, and includes 14 two-storey houses, 65 residential units, a fitness centre, training pitch, a restaurant, a pool area and easy access to the beach. A football youth academy and an orphanage will be built on the site as well.
>
> The location was chosen as it is within 2 hours flight of the team's group games to minimise travel, and is a short trip to the airport. It will also allow acclimatisation to the weather, as well as good security.
>
> Completion was originally scheduled for March 2014, and there have been worries it may not be fully complete for the start of the World Cup. According to media reports, the resort was completed just days before the arrival of the national team.

Comment: So, it is a case od 'speculazione edilizia'?

Answer (score 3):

The Germans did build their own training camp for the World Cup, called **Campo Bahia**,  in Santo André, south of the state of Bahia. The project was a collaboration between German businesses and the German Football Federation (DFB).

> The beachside grounds span 15,000 square metres and, within that area, there are 14 two-storey villas comprising 64 residential units. Each villa is housing up to six players of the 23-man squad as well as members of a 39-strong backroom staff. Within Campo Bahia, there is also an outdoor swimming pool, a spa, a lounge and dining area, a fitness centre, communal lounges and an auditorium for team meetings [[1]](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/germany/10962216/World-Cup-2014-Germanys-purpose-built-training-camp-has-given-them-extra-edge.html)

There was a lot of myths and speculation on what would happen to the hotel. False Facebook threads saying that the hotel would be donated, and even this [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/football/25370272) that said that "A football youth academy and an orphanage will be built on the site" (I only found this information in non-Brazilian media outlets. I searched for Portuguese references for it. I couldn't find anything that linked a German football team and an orphanage.)

But in the end, the hotel was opened for business as a luxury hotel:

> A diária mais "suave" no Campo Bahia custa 600 euros (R$ 1,8 mil), para uma vila com quatro quartos, e a mais cara, 2,5 mil euros (R$ 7,5 mil), para uma vila com seis quartos [[3]](http://esportes.r7.com/futebol/copa-do-mundo-2014/concentracao-da-selecao-alema-na-copa-vira-hotel-de-luxo-na-bahia-17072014)
>
> (translated) The most affordable daily price in Campo Bahia costs 600 euros (R$ 1800) for a *villa* with 4 rooms, and the most expensive costs, 2500 euros (R$ 7500) for a *villa* with 6 rooms